# Upgrade a previous version with InstallShield

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield, installshield-le

I'm using InstallShield 2013 LE, and I wondered if there is an ability to upgrade a previous version with an UpgradePath in the new setup (there is no upgrade path in the old setup)? The upgrade code is the same, and the product code & product versions are different. Should it works?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The upgrade will work.  You could make the new MSI in a new tool such as WIX and as long as the upgrade code is the same,  it will upgrade.
Remember there are two options for an upgrade,  you can do a patch or small upgrade and keep the production code the same or just change the product code and do a full upgrade.